# Showing variable name in table output when using `modify_caption` in gtsummary with glue packages

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval, gtsummary, r-glue

I want to write a code that uses `dplyr::select()`, `gtsummary::tbl_summary()` and `glue::glue()`.

The plan is:

- select a few variables from a dataframe (for example : all numerical variables)
- return a table summary based a grouping variable (a factor variable)
- and in the table, the caption should show the **grouping variable**

I will be using the **gapminder** dataset to demo the error.

The expected table is

[image]

Below, I demo what I have done

First, I load the libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(gapminder)
library(gtsummary)
```

And write my function

```
describe_grp <- function(data, group){
  data %>%
    tbl_summary(by = group) %>% add_p() %>%
    modify_caption(glue::glue("Detection For **{group}**")) %>%
    bold_labels()
}
```

But I need to use `'continent'` (see codes below). It works like I wanted.

```
gapminder %>%
  select(is.integer, is.double, continent) %>%
  describe_grp(group = 'continent')
```

But, my preferred choice is *not to use the hyphen*, that is to use  `describe_grp(group = continent)`.

So I thought I could use

- `enquo()`
- or `{{ }}` curly curly

However, both do not work. My guess it has something to do with `glue::glue()` function in `modify_caption()`

See below for the codes that **do not work**:

```
#using enquo
describe_grp2 <- function(data, group){
  egroup <- enquo(group)
  data %>%
    tbl_summary(by = !!egroup) %>% add_p() %>%
    modify_caption(glue::glue("Detection For {(!!egroup)}")) %>%
    bold_labels()
}

gapminder %>%
  select(is.integer, is.double, continent) %>%
  describe_grp2(group = continent)
```

These codes also **don't work**

```
#using curly curly
describe_grp3 <- function(data, group){
  data %>%
    tbl_summary(by = {{group}}) %>% add_p() %>%
    modify_caption(glue::glue("Detection For **{{{group}}}**")) %>%
    bold_labels()
}

gapminder %>%
  select(is.integer, is.double, continent) %>%
  describe_grp3(group = continent)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use -

```
describe_grp <- function(data, group){
  group_val <- deparse(substitute(group))
  data %>%
    tbl_summary(by = {{group}}) %>% add_p() %>%
    modify_caption(glue::glue("Detection For **{group_val}**"))  %>%
    bold_labels()
}

gapminder %>%
  select(is.integer, is.double, continent) %>%
  describe_grp(group = continent)
```

[image]

Comment: `group_val <- substitute(group))` without deparse works also. Do we need `deparse`?

Comment: Ohh.okay. Doesn't seem necessary then.

Comment: `deparse()` may return a character vector of length > 1 in some edge cases. It's better to use `as_label()` to avoid this problem.

Comment: this `group_val <- substitute(group)) ` is exactly what I need.